# Usage of 'it is' or 'is it' in questions

Tags: grammaticality

Who can tell me what day is it today? Or Who can tell me what day it is today?
Which is correct grammatically?

Comment: Welcome, Yavar.  If you don't mind, please may you consider expanding this into a proper question?  We prefer questions with actual context and research, so they're fully fleshed out.  See [How to Ask.](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

"what day it is today" is a noun clause in your sentence, the direct object of the verb *tell*, and thus cannot be in an interrogative form.
so your second sentence is the way to go.

Comment: I wouldn't go along with that. "what day it is today" is a subordinate content clause (embedded question) functioning as **complement** of "tell". It means "Who can tell me the answer to the question 'What day is it today?' "

Answer (score 0):

In direct questions, the subect and the verb (or auxiliary) are usually inverted:

> What day **is it** today.

In indirect questions, they are not usually inverted:

> Who can tell me *what day **it is** today*.